# Is it true that having no prior connections with the university makes me a less desirable candidate?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, university

I've just finished a conversation with a professor at *University X*. The majority of questions were on topics regarding the graduate admission. A quote that has both negative and confusing effects on me

> It is almost impossible to get accepted *normally*. Aside from sending in all the required documents, passing the tests (GRE, IELTS), having a good GPA score, etc. the only chance to be admitted is to have ongoing, strong research and collaboration with the faculty.

However, the admission criteria states that only the particular set of documents is required. Can it be true that having no prior connections with the university makes me a less desirable candidate?

Comment: All else being equal, are you going to choose the person you know already or the complete stranger?

Comment: @Nij "the person you know" == "professor" and "stranger" == "the university homepage" ?

Comment: No. "The person you know" is the candidate with ongoing, strong research and collaboration. "The stranger" is you.

Comment: Even if the stranger might be a good candidate? It sounds unfair to my ears.

Comment: All else being equal, it is fair. You might be good. You might also be terrible. You might be just a fraud. **They don't know you.**

Comment: Even if the professor you spoke with from University X is wrong, the fact that he was so discouraging and snotty does not create a positive impression of University X.  Maybe consider some other options.

Comment: @aparente001: To me, the quote reads more like the professor is openly pointing out the actual situation without creating false hopes. While it may indeed be (realistically) discouraging, I would not consider it "snotty", and moreover, that openness creates an excellent impression at least of that particular professor to me. The resulting conclusion, though, is of course the same as yours :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I think it may be a difference of culture (i.e. different countries).

Answer (score 4):

I could be misreading this but it sounds like he means that to get in, someone actually has to want you.  I think he's saying it's unlikely you would be admitted to some sort of incoming class of new graduate students and then get assigned to an adviser as you likely experienced as an UG.

One big reason for the difference can be the money.  At many (most?) research universities, if they accept you as a PhD student, you will be funded.  But that funding has to come from somewhere.  If it's not from some big department pool but from an individual faculty member's grant money that they sweated to get, they're going to want to pick someone they like, not uncommonly someone they already know and have worked with.

Comment: Yes, you've got me correct. Strange, but some students (including myself) are aware that education costs money and are actually searching for ways to get financial aid. So even if I am eager to pay the money, they are not willing to accept me?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, the answer can be no.  If they only take PhD students for whom they have funding, they may not care that you'd be willing to self-fund.  It's just not how they work.

Comment: And the application process? Yet another fundraiser for them?

Comment: No.  It just means that if you're going to spend the money applying, you might as well think about how the admissions decision will likely be made.  Since it matters if someone actually wants you, one thing you might do is consider if there's a way to make that happen.  You might browse through the faculty bios to find people with interests similar to yours.  Send each an email, introducing yourself and asking if they're accepting new advisees.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton - There are departments with lots of TAships, and there are departments with very few TAships.  It sounds like you are extrapolating from your field and assuming all fields are like yours.

Comment: I could be wrong about all of this but no, I don't think it's about TAships, it's about how the department works.  For example, I happen to know that the EE department on our main campus will not admit a PhD student unless they have funding and they do not care if a student is willing to self-fund.  Period.  It's sounded to me like this is what the OP was being told is the case at University X.